# DOM element becomes Null in Vue project

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working on a code typer, but for some reason the element becomes `Null` with no reason I can make out. I am new to Vue & know this code works as I've previously completed this at https://CodeSpent.dev (live preview) in Django/Python until I determined it'd be valuable to learn more front end frameworks.

So I believe it has something to do with how Vue handles rendering, but I'm only a few hours into learning & have no idea where to even look with this.

**Here is the code:**

```
  var codeBlock = document.getElementById('code')
  console.log(codeBlock)
  setTimeout(() => {

    new TypeIt(codeBlock, {
      strings: [codeSample],
      speed: 20
    }).go();

  }, 1000)

  setInterval(function () {

    const code = Prism.highlight(codeBlock.innerText, Prism.languages.python, 'python');
    document.getElementById('real-code').innerHTML = code;
  }, 10);
```

If we look at console we can see on line 23 where `codeBlock` is clearly not null, but then when we try to use it it becomes `null`. Anything stand out?
[image]

**Full Component:**

```
<template>
  <div id="code-block" class="bb">
    <pre class="code-pre">
    <code id="real-code"></code>
  </pre>

    <div id="code" class="language-py"></div>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
  import 'prismjs'
  import 'prismjs/themes/prism.css'
  import TypeIt from 'typeit';

  export default {
    name: 'CodeTyper'
  }

  var codeSample = '\x0a\x3E\x3E\x20\x6E\x61\x6E\x6F\x20\x63\x6F\x64\x65\x73\x70\x65\x6E\x74\x2E\x70\x79\x0A\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x20\x70\x79\x74\x68\x6F\x6E\x20\x69\x6D\x70\x6F\x72\x74\x20\x44\x65\x76\x65\x6C\x6F\x70\x65\x72\x0A\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x20\x70\x6F\x72\x74\x66\x6F\x6C\x69\x6F\x2E\x6D\x6F\x64\x65\x6C\x73\x20\x69\x6D\x70\x6F\x72\x74\x20\x50\x6F\x72\x74\x66\x6F\x6C\x69\x6F\x0A\x0A\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x20\x43\x6F\x64\x65\x53\x70\x65\x6E\x74\x28\x44\x65\x76\x65\x6C\x6F\x70\x65\x72\x29\x3A\x0A\x20\x20\x20\x20\x6E\x61\x6D\x65\x20\x3D\x20\x27\x50\x61\x74\x72\x69\x63\x6B\x20\x48\x61\x6E\x66\x6F\x72\x64\x27\x0A\x20\x20\x20\x20\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x20\x20\x3D\x20\x27\x50\x69\x74\x74\x73\x62\x75\x72\x67\x68\x2C\x20\x50\x41\x2C\x20\x55\x53\x27\x0A\x20\x20\x20\x20\x6C\x61\x6E\x67\x75\x61\x67\x65\x73\x20\x3D\x20\x5B\x27\x70\x79\x74\x68\x6F\x6E\x27\x2C\x20\x27\x6A\x61\x76\x61\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x27\x2C\x20\x27\x63\x73\x73\x27\x2C\x27\x68\x74\x6D\x6C\x35\x27\x5D\x0A\x20\x20\x20\x20\x66\x61\x76\x6F\x72\x69\x74\x65\x73\x20\x3D\x20\x5B\x27\x64\x6A\x61\x6E\x67\x6F\x27\x2C\x20\x27\x74\x65\x6E\x73\x6F\x72\x66\x6C\x6F\x77\x27\x2C\x20\x27\x74\x77\x69\x74\x63\x68\x27\x2C\x20\x27\x64\x69\x73\x63\x6F\x72\x64\x27\x2C\x20\x27\x6F\x70\x65\x6E\x63\x76\x27\x5D\x0A\x0A\x20\x20\x20\x20\x64\x65\x66\x20\x5F\x5F\x73\x74\x72\x5F\x5F\x28\x73\x65\x6C\x66\x29\x3A\x0A\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6E\x20\x73\x65\x6C\x66\x2E\x6E\x61\x6D\x65'
  var codeBlock = document.getElementById('code')
  console.log(codeBlock)
  setTimeout(() => {

    new TypeIt(codeBlock, {
      strings: [codeSample],
      speed: 20
    }).go();

  }, 1000)

  setInterval(function () {

    const code = Prism.highlight(codeBlock.innerText, Prism.languages.python, 'python');
    document.getElementById('real-code').innerHTML = code;
  }, 10);


</script>

<style>
  #real-code {
    color: #5c5edc;
  }

  #code-block {
  background-color: #141D22;
  color: #fff;
  flex: 1;
  height: 355px;
}

#code-block-sub {
  background-color: rgb(34, 32, 35);
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 15px;
  height: 150px;
}

#code,
#code-sub {
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
  display: none;
  color: #fff !important;
}


</style>
```

Comment: From my limited understanding of vue, the use of getElement seems wrong.  I think you should bind a string into a template, then on a timer append chars to that string.  The point of vue is to allow the dom to be updated as a side effect of modifying the data.

Comment: That makes sense, let me see.

Comment: Would you be able to post an example? In theory I understand what you're saying, but I'm a bit stumped applying it.

Comment: yep.  good exercise for me to learn something, too.  will post in a few mins...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a template that presents the partial string...

```
<template>
  <div>
    <pre>{{partialCode}}</pre>
    <v-btn @click="startAppending()"></v-btn>
  </div>
</template>
```

Then the `partialCode` string bound into data...

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      partialCode: '',
      // other data
    }
  },
```

You may want to start appending onCreate or some other lifecycle hook (or once you receive the code data asynchronously), but the key to the logic is that you can now just change the state of partialCode and let the DOM update itself...

```
  methods: {
    startAppending() {
      this.partialCode = ''  // start fresh each time
      const code = Prism.highlight(codeBlock.innerText, Prism.languages.python, 'python')
      let index = 0
      let interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (this.partialCode.length === code.length) {
          clearInterval(interval)
        } else {
          this.partialCode = code.slice(0, index++)
        }
      }, 200);
    },
    // the other methods
  }
```

Comment: Now `partialCode` is meant to be identical to my `codeSample` correct?

Comment: In Prism instantiation you're still referencing the innerText of `codeBlock` to highlight. `code` is the instance of Prism with highlighted text, but `partialCode` is basically being treated as the same thing in this example. I don't see where `codeSample` is being used to append the proper text, and I'm getting a render error on `partialCode`. Could you drop your test project in https://codesandbox.io/ so I can interact with it a bit & reproduce what I'm seeing?

Comment: @CodeSpent, another thing that's new to me, but try this...https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-jm0th

Comment: Ah okay, so I see what's different. The main reason I needed to access the DOM is for Prism. On an interval as the code is typed I need Prism to handle the highlighting of the text that's currently inside which this wouldn't really be able to do out of the box, but I'll look into it. Nonetheless this helps & at least puts me on a better path to solving this issue so I'll accept this! Thank you.